# Have dropzone.js send to different form handler on fallback

Tags: php, jquery, dropzone.js

Using Dropzone.js, is there any way to have the fallback form send uploaded files to a different php handler?

So if a user is using the full Dropzone.js interface, it uses "dropzone.php" to handle the file uploads, but if the user has an old and unsuported browser and the script renders in fallback mode, then it uses "dropzonefallback.php" to handle the file uploads.

I tried hardcoding a url into what seems to be the fallback form code in dropzone.js, but this doesnt work:

```
  if (this.element.tagName !== "FORM") {
    form = Dropzone.createElement("<form action=\"dropzonefallback.php\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"" + this.options.method + "\"></form>");
    form.appendChild(fields);
  } else {
    this.element.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    this.element.setAttribute("method", this.options.method);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it!

The script must have been in the lower half of the "if" statement, and doing the following does what I wanted it to:

```
  if (this.element.tagName !== "FORM") {
    form = Dropzone.createElement("<form action=\"dropzonefallback.php\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"" + this.options.method + "\"></form>");
    form.appendChild(fields);
  } else {
    this.element.setAttribute("action", "dropzonefallback.php");
    this.element.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    this.element.setAttribute("method", this.options.method);
  }
```